# VueJs component not being replaced with the template

Tags: vue.js

When trying to render a component, the template string is rendering not where the component is defined in the HTML. Instead, the rendered HTML is getting rendered outside of my `<table>`.

Easiest way to describe this is with the code snippet below. `Column 2` is appearing outside the `<table>` altogether, even tho I have `<my-th></my-th>` directly after my `<th>Column 1</th>`.

Why is this happening?

```js
Vue.component('my-th', {
    props: [],
    template: `<th>Column 2</th>`
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```css
body { background: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <my-th></my-th><!-- Column 2 -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Vue's special `is` attribute in this scenario.

The browser will parse the HTML before Vue gets anywhere near it and any elements inside a table that aren't where they're supposed to be will be moved out. The browser doesn't know what a `my-th` is so it moves it out to before the `table`.

This is specifically a problem with templates defined in HTML where it will be parsed by the browser first. For the various other ways to specify a template it isn't an issue as Vue can see the template in its original form.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats for details.

```js
Vue.component('my-th', {
    props: [],
    template: `<th>Column 2</th>`
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```css
body { background: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th is="my-th"></th><!-- Column 2 -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```